# Jenkins and SAML plugin issues using SSO Auth

Tags: plugins, jenkins, saml

Jenkins v 1.597
SAML plugin v 0.3

We are using an internal PingFederated server and I have entered the xml metedata contents into the Security configuration of Jenkins.

I have tried on two servers, one set up HTTPS (SSL) and one just HTTP.

We get errors when trying to login using SSO that pertain to the https://servername/securityRealm/finishLogin redirect and the same for non-SSL server.

We are stumped on what to check here, the PingFederated administrator has it set for the postback to the securityRealm/finishLogin URL, which is what is in the code for the plugin, we just are not sure how to proceed.

The contents of the xml metadata:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="MNkL_uYrUsdEca2oWqH6gdgG4t3" cacheDuration="PT1440M" entityID="ACIWW:Saml2:POC" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"><md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false"><md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data>   <ds:X509Certificate>CERTIFICATECODE HERE</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data>    </ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://SSOSERVERNAME/idp/SSO.saml2"/><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://SSOSERVERNAME/idp/SSO.saml2"/><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://SSOSERVERNAME/idp/SSO.saml2"/><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://SSOSERVERNAME/idp/SSO.saml2"/></md:IDPSSODescriptor><md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative"><md:Company>COMPANYNAME</md:Company></md:ContactPerson></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

John